# +exposeBinding not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, xcode4

I'm trying to expose a custom binding in an subclass of an NSWindowController.  I added the following code to the subclass:

`+(void)initialize { [self exposeBinding:@"customBinding"];  }`

Then, in IB, I have an object instance of my subclass.  But, when I look at the bindings of the custom NSWindowController, I don't see the 'customBinding' exposed.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These methods are for use in legacy Interface Builder plug-ins only. Xcode 4 doesn't officially support plug-ins. You have create these bindings in code using [`-bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSKeyValueBindingCreation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002048-BCICHGHC). The “type whatever you like” part only applies to the key paths you bind to, not to the binding names themselves.

Comment: So Xcode4 no longer supports custom bindings?  Why isn't this function depreciated then?

Comment: Apple might just not have decided yet. Maybe we’ll get plug-in support in an update to Xcode 4 (though I don’t think that’s likely). Or, with the new LLVM-based indexing system, Xcode could theoretically gather custom binding info without actually executing the code. To be honest, though, I just think they didn’t get around to updating the documentation to reflect this.

Comment: XCode 4 does not support plugins? How wrong you are: http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/creating-an-xcode4-plugin/, http://www.inline-studios.com/developer/articles/1-Xcode_4_Interface_Builder_Plugins/, http://cocoanaut.com/useful-xcode-4-plugins/. To name a few sites.

Comment: Of course you can hack your way into a closed system, but even two of the links you posted make it clear that there is no official support from Apple. Plus, this type of plug-in has little to do with what plug-ins in the standalone IB days used to be. (I’ve now added the word ‘officially’ in my post above so that even nitpickers might realise that unofficial hacks have nothing to do with what IB 3 supported and are no replacement for a stable API.)

Answer (score 0):

These are only if you're creating an IB palette/plugin. From [Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/HowDoBindingsWork.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002373-174515):

> The other methods—the class method `exposeBinding:` and the instance methods `exposedBindings` and `valueClassForBinding:`—are useful only in an Interface Builder palette.

When setting up bindings, you can just type in whatever key paths you like; they don't have to be exposed in IB.

Comment: That page is 2 years old and doesn't talk about IB plugins in Xcode 4.  Not sure how to create one.  Also, not sure what you mean by "just typ in whatever key paths you like".  Where?  I'm trying to not bind programmatically, but via IB - so I don't have to expose IBOutlets.

Comment: You can bind to any property that uses Key-Value Coding-compliant accessor methods, you don't need to specifically mark the bindings as exposed. If you've created `@property` declarations with their implementations created using `@synthesize` then you have KVC-compliant accessors. Bindings have nothing to do with IBOutlets.