# What does exposeBinding do?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have been using bindings without having ever heard of `exposeBinding`.

Is it only intended to plug-ins ?

**What does `exposeBinding` do ?**

Comment: Check this other answer out. Looks like it's only for Xcode plugs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058282/exposebinding-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSKeyValueBindingCreation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

`exposeBinding:`

Exposes the specified binding, advertising its availability.

Answer (score 1):

Expose bindings are nothing special, it is just normal binding what you see in the Xcode. But why its named is expose binding becuase when you do any binding in the interface builder. It causes second binding automatically in the interface builder which is called expose binding.

For your understanding i have attached the screen shot in which inside binding inspector i have just bind file owner to the hidden in Availablity section and then you can see below automatically it created hidden2 inside Availablity section below. This new binding hidden2 is called exposed binding. And also the used of these binding values are then used together in returning the final value of the binding. Please follow the attached screen shot:-

[image]

Comment: For more description you can go to this documents https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CocoaBindingsRef/Concepts/BindingTypes.html