# How do I add my own properties to the Bindings Inspector in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

When editing a .xib in Xcode, I can select a view or other object, navigate to the "Bindings" tab in the Inspector, and bind its properties to properties of other objects. This is all well and good, but if I create my own subclass and add new properties, those properties won't appear in the list, and I'm having trouble finding an up-to-date solution for adding them.

I'm aware that I can create the binding at runtime using `bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:`, but that doesn't seem like a very elegant solution, as it's clunkier than setting up a binding normally is, and adding glue code kind of defeats the purpose of using bindings. The only method I've seen is to create something called an IBPlugin, but I'm hearing Xcode stopped supporting IBPlugins ages ago when it and Interface Builder were merged into a single program.

So how can I do this? I tried `@IBInspectable`, which makes properties settable in the inspector, but it doesn't look like that makes them bindable.

Comment: Not sure why this would get downvoted. I don't know the answer, but now I want to know as well. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058282/exposebinding-not-working) makes me think these bindings were deprecated a long time ago.

Comment: You can bind to whatever keypath you want, just paste or type the keypath. Xcode doesn't know the keypath but your app at runtime will.

Comment: Or do you want to bind your own properties to something else? The question isn't very clear.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, I want to bind my own properties to something else. I actually just found that if I bind a different property, then open the XIB in a text editor and manually change the binding's key path, my custom property will appear, but I'd have to do that every time I want to set up the binding. Still, seems more elegant than writing code to do it at runtime.

Comment: Does the binding work? Both ways?

Comment: @Willeke How should I test that?

Comment: If you bind A to B, does A change when B changes and does B change when A changes?

Comment: @Willeke: That's what I thought I tried, but I must not have set up the custom view correctly because it only worked one way, and that was the case even if I used `bind:` to do it at runtime.